# how to make the primary key not unique and auto-increment migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

I'm newbie in Laravel and I want to create a niveaux (level) with several filieres (field of studies) like the following query because I have a table level that can include many filieres.

```
INSERT INTO `ismo_project`.`niveaux` (`id`, `nom`, `id_filieres`) VALUES ('1', '1 année', '2');
INSERT INTO `ismo_project`.`niveaux` (`id`, `nom`, `id_filieres`) VALUES ('1', '1 année', '1');
```

but i can't since the id by default is unique and auto increment I have tried several methods but it stays the same. here is my migrations file of table niveaux:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('niveaux', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id')->primary();
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_filieres');
            $table->foreign('id_filieres')->references('id')->on('filieres')->onDelete('cascade');  
        });
    }
```

my model file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Niveau extends Model
{   
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable=[
        'nom',
        'id_filieres',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function niveau(){
        return $this->hasMany(Niveau::class,'id_niveaux');
    }
}
```

I hope you can help

Comment: If primary will also be unique. I cannot understand your goal anyway

Comment: @Jack what I'm trying to do is the same niveau with same id can have different filieres

Comment: take a look at many to many relationship in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Follow example:

```php
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Comment: bigIncrements() doesn't also auto-increment the id and make it unique?

Comment: I think Laravel 10 using this for id!